# Is the click a part of install cost?

Tags: android-netrunner

The card says something like "paying install cost" ([Hayley Kaplan](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08025), [Shipment from MirrorMorpt](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01060)). Is the click a part of install cost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. From the [core rule book](http://ancur.wikia.com/wiki/Core_Rule_Book#Important_Vocabulary):

> Install: This is the game term for playing a card onto the table.

This could be done [as an action, during the Action Phase](http://ancur.wikia.com/wiki/Core_Rule_Book#2._Action_Phase), but in the examples you're talking about it is triggered because of card text. A click cost is not inherent in an install, just as "click, $2" is not inherent in trashing a resource or removing a tag, and playing Diesel does not result in spending 4 clicks to draw 3 cards.

And aside from all of that, if the install off of Hayley did cost a click, that would make her ability MUCH less good, to the point of irrelevance.